# SAS - Drop or Output Columns Matching Condition on the ColumnID

Tags: sas

Is there a way to drop a group of columns in SAS, all matching some conditional statement? In this case I want to drop any column that has the SUFFIX "_fix"

The alternative is to output all columns without "_fix" but the main question here being, how do I perform logic on column names?

EDIT:
I'm currently using this but its not the most elegant I suppose

```
proc contents data= your_data_set noprint out= _data_ ; run;
proc sql noprint ;
select name into :list_of_cols separated by ' ' from &syslast
where lowcase(name) like '%_flg' ;
quit;
```

then use &list_of_cols

SOURCE: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/drop-variant/td-p/71230

Comment: Well ugh, before your edit I was writing up your current solution.  It's a common solution to the problem.  Another option is to use SQL to query dictionary.columns, but that isn't more elegant (and often is less efficient).  I have seen fancy function-style macros that return a list of variables from a dataset, which you could call like `%put Vars ending in flag: %varlist(data=mydatasets,suffix=_flg)`.  But most folks would not consider the macro code elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the effort sorry for the trouble! :)

Comment: If you have any control over naming conventions, SAS allows variable shortcuts based on prefixes but not suffixes. If you can change it to a prefix it's easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc contents data= your_data_set noprint out= _data_ ; run;
proc sql noprint ;

select name into :list_of_cols separated by ' ' from &syslast
where lowcase(name) like '%_fix' ;
quit;
```